# will 10 year old refusals affect current visa application?

Tags: visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, applications, proof-of-ties

I have been refused twice in 2009 and 2010 for J1 visas, it's been almost 10 years now and I want to apply for the B1B2 visa. Will the previous refusal affect the current application even though a lot of changes have occurred in my status?

I was in university when I was refused, I am now finished and am also now working in a state owned health insurance company. I also own a house, am married and have a child, and I have also completed another degree and am gainfully employed.

So, will the previous refusal affect my new application?

Comment: The previous refusals will be on record of course, but a lot of time has passed and on the face of it you now seem to be able to tick all the boxes regarding overcoming the US assumption of immigrant intent.

Answer (score 1):

When you are asked "have you ever been refused a visa", you say yes and explain what happened back then. You just didn't meet the requirements nine or ten years ago, but that shouldn't cause any problems as long as your situation has changed and you meet the requirements today. If you had been refused a visa two weeks ago, that might be a problem.

If you are asked the same question and answer "no", then 99% they will find out, and the fact that you lied would most likely mean you are refused a visa, and might get a ban, even if you would easily have got the visa if you had said the truth. So don't lie about it.

Comment: Thanks boss am very grateful but the previous refusal o was not given any specific reason but I suspect they refuse me base on unable to provide enough documents so in this case if they ask me why was I refuse can I say I COULDN'T MEET THE REQUIREMENTS  that's why I was refused can I say this